# Cannot assign values to a 'double slice' using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

How would I do the following in numpy?

1. select all rows of an array containing note more than 50% 0 values.
2. select first `n` (let's say 2) rows from all rows satisfying 1.
3. do something and place modified rows on same index of a zero array with equal shape of 1.

The following results in an array where no new values are assigned:

```
In [177]:    
a = np.array([[0,0,3],[4,5,6],[7,0,0],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]])
b = np.zeros_like(a)
a
Out[177]:    
array([[ 0,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  0,  0],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])

In [178]:
# select all rows containg note more than 50% 0 values
percent = np.sum(a == 0, axis=-1) / float(check.shape[1])
percent = percent >= 0.5
slice = np.invert(percent).nonzero()[0]

In [183]:
# select first two rows satisfying 'slice'
a[slice][0:2] 

Out[183]:    
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12]])

In [182]:
# do something and place modified rows on same index of zero array
b[slice][0:2] = a[slice][0:2] * 2

In [184]:
b
Out[184]:    
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `b[slice][0:2] = a[slice][0:2] * 2` (note on the RHS we're now indexing `a` rather than `b`).

Comment: In any case, it would probably be better to define `slice = np.invert(percent).nonzero()[0][:2]` and then use `b[slice] = a[slice] * 2`.

Comment: @ajcr that was a typo, RHS should indeed index 'a'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `b[slice]` creates a copy rather than a view (it triggers fancy indexing). The code `b[slice][0:2]` creates a view of this copy (not the original `b`!). Therefore...

```
b[slice][0:2] = a[slice][0:2] * 2
```

...is assigning the corresponding rows of `a` to a view of the copy of `b`.

Because it can lead to these situations, it's better not to chain indexing operations in this way. Instead, just compute the relevant row numbers for `slice` first and then do the assignment:

```
slice = np.invert(percent).nonzero()[0][:2] # first two rows
b[slice] = a[slice] * 2
```