# Numpy double-slice assignment with integer indexing followed by boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I already know that Numpy "double-slice" with fancy indexing creates copies instead of views, and the solution seems to be to convert them to one single slice (e.g. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764141/cannot-assign-values-to-a-double-slice-using-numpy)). However, I am facing this particular problem where i need to deal with an integer indexing followed by boolean indexing and I am at a loss what to do. The problem (simplified) is as follows:

```
a = np.random.randn(2, 3, 4, 4)
idx_x = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]])
idx_y = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
print(a[..., idx_y, idx_x].shape) # (2, 3, 3, 2)
mask = (np.random.randn(2, 3, 3, 2) > 0)
a[..., idx_y, idx_x][mask] = 1 # assignment doesn't work
```

How can I make the assignment work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok apparently I am making things complicated. No need to combine the indexing. The following code solves the problem elegantly:

```
b = a[..., idx_y, idx_x]
b[mask] = 1
a[..., idx_y, idx_x] = b
print(a[..., idx_y, idx_x][mask]) # all 1s
```

Comment: D'oh! I'm sure I tried this out when wrapping my head around the re-indexing! I'm glad it works out - typical we all make our lives harder than we need to... time for bed! Nice one.

Comment: Nice. ```a[..., idx_x, idx_y] *= ~mask; a[..., idx_x, idx_y] += mask * 1``` should also work if you want to do it arithmetically :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but an idea is to do the broadcasting manually and adding the `mask`  respectively just like Tim suggests. `idx_x` and `idx_y` both have the same shape `(3,2)` which will be broadcasted to the shape `(6,6)` from the cartesian product (3*2)^2.

```
x = np.broadcast_to(idx_x.ravel(), (6,6))
y = np.broadcast_to(idx_y.ravel(), (6,6))

# this should be the same as
x,y = np.meshgrid(idx_x, idx_y)
```

Now reshape the mask to the broadcasted indices and use it to select

```
mask = mask.reshape(6,6)
a[..., x[mask], y[mask]] = 1
```

The assignment now *works*, but I am not sure if this is the exact assignment you wanted.

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out just now - I was getting myself mixed up with the dimensions! I was going to suggest a solution using `np.ravel` and `np.tile` but this is much neater. I'll leave yours as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Just tried again with a simple test case - a few notes
```python
a = np.arange(27).reshape([3, 3, 3]);
ind_x = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 2]]);
ind_y = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1]]);
# x = np.broadcast_to(ind_x.ravel(), (4, 4));
# y = np.broadcast_to(ind_y.ravel(), (4, 4)).T;
x, y = np.meshgrid(ind_x, ind_y);
mask = a[:, ind_y, ind_x] % 2 == 0;
```
1. I think `y` from `meshgrid` is actually `y.T`
2. In this 3D example, how should we reshape `mask`?
It shouldn't be hard but I can't get my head around it at the moment!

Comment: @TimJim you're right the ```y``` from meshgrid is transposed - but the principle remains the same. I am not sure on what the exact input and output should be, maybe OP can provide an example? The code snippet you pasted here is a bit hard to read, maybe you could edit your post with it formatted?

Comment: The assignment works but its not the same assignment. You can check with `a[..., idx_y, idx_x][mask]` (where `mask` is the original mask, not modified) and not all of them has changed to 1.

Comment: The exact input and output is much more complicated (it comes from the backward process of a max pooling layer, idx_x and idx_y are fancy indices to reshape the array so that each 2x2 block is rearranged into an axis, and `mask` is true for elements with gradient = 1and false for those with gradient = 0. I wish to assign gradients with the line `d_loss_d_inputs[..., self.idx_y, self.idx_x][self.max_mask] = d_loss_d_output.flatten()`. This is part of a project to rebuild CNN with numpy from scratch), but I pretty much just need the sample code to work :)

Comment: I think we're pretty close to the right answer, we just need to make sure we're unwrapping/unstacking the dimensions correctly and reshaping the mask accordingly. I reckon if you can get the simple 3-dimensional example I set up in EDIT2 working, you'll be able to apply it to your example =) In the example, it's a simple 3x3 grid running from 0 to 26, and you can try to pick out the even numbers to see if you can get the mask working. Right now, I can't figure out how we need to reshare your data. I'll sleep on it and see if it comes clear overnight

Comment: oh god i missed the apparent solution. thanks to all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Use @Kevin's solution which actually gets the dimensions correct!

---

I haven't tried it specifically on your sample code but I had a similar issue before. I think I solved it by applying the mask to the indices instead, something like:

```py
a[..., idx_y[mask], idx_x[mask]] = 1
```

-that way, numpy can assign the values to the `a` array correctly.

---

EDIT2: Post some test code as comments remove formatting.

```py
a = np.arange(27).reshape([3, 3, 3])
ind_x = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 2]])
ind_y = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1]])
x = np.broadcast_to(ind_x.ravel(), (4, 4))
y = np.broadcast_to(ind_y.ravel(), (4, 4)).T
# x1, y2 = np.meshgrid(ind_x, ind_y)  # above should be the same as this
mask = a[:, ind_y, ind_x] % 2 == 0  # what should this reshape to?
# a[..., x[mask], y[mask]] = 1  # Then you can mask away (may also need to reshape a or the masked x or y)
```

Comment: Apparently this does not work. `mask` is 4-dimensional but `idx_y` is only 2-dimensional.

Comment: @Jerry Sorry, I hadn't checked the dimensions - you should use Kevin's answer. The idea is to apply your second mask to the first and index with that.

Comment: I'll try to work through this example, but for now i will stick with the easy solution :) thanks